# Integer value on mysql has changed when retrieve from delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

I use mysql as my database that is connected to ODBC using mySQLconnectorODBC. In my table has 2 integer field : index (auto_inc) and tall(3), and 1 varchar field : person_name(50).
The problem is when I retrieve using delphi (xe2) from data explorer, the integer value has change, for example it's change from 0 to 512, 2 -> 1026, 3 -> 262147, etc. But when I change varchar length from 50 to 35, the integer value is normal, doesn't change. Why? Does anyone got same problem?

Comment: There's an arbitrary high-bit in your malformed values. E.g. 3 -> 1000000000000000011

Comment: Which integer, `index` or `tall` ?  Also how are you populating the tables?

Comment: the value in all integer type of field was changed, 
example, 
mysql:

index | person_name | tall 
==========================
   0    mr. a          100
   1    mr. b          120

when read from delphi it's changed like :

index | person_name | tall
==========================
  0     mr. a         525670
 513    mr. b         6264234323